# Why does unity playmode freeze the editor when using this script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Whenever i enter playmode with this script enabled, unity freezes and stops responding, only being able to stop using task manager. The only way to open playmode is to disable the script. Someone had a problem where there was an infinite loop, but i don't think that this applies here.
Here is the script using the problem:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text timer;
    public TMP_Text DifTextpro;
    public float time;
    float msec;
    float sec;
    float min;
    public static float dif = 0;
    public string diftext;

    private void Start(){
        StartCoroutine("StopWatch");
        BlockSpawner.timeBetweenWaves = Random.Range(5.2f, 6f);
    }

    

    IEnumerator StopWatch(){
        while (true)
        {
            time += Time.deltaTime;
           
            sec = (int)(time % 60);
            min = (int)(time / 60 % 60);

            timer.text = string.Format("{0:00} : {1:00}",min,sec);
            if(dif == 1){

                if(dif == 2){
                    
                    if (dif == 3){
                        if(min == 4 && sec == 15){
                        dif = 3;
                        diftext = "Extreme";
                        DifTextpro.text = diftext;
                        BlockSpawner.timeBetweenWaves = Random.Range(1.2f, 2f);

                    }else{
                        if(min == 2 && sec == 30){
                        dif = 3;
                        diftext = "Very Hard";
                        DifTextpro.text = diftext;
                        BlockSpawner.timeBetweenWaves = Random.Range(2f, 3f);
                    }
                }
                }
                else{
                    if(min == 1 && sec == 15){
                    dif = 2;
                    diftext = "Hard";
                    DifTextpro.text = diftext;
                    BlockSpawner.timeBetweenWaves = Random.Range(3f, 4f);
                }
                    
                }
            }
            else{
                if(sec == 30){
                        dif = 1;
                        diftext = "Normal";
                        DifTextpro.text = diftext;
                        BlockSpawner.timeBetweenWaves = Random.Range(4f, 5.2f);

                    }
            }
            

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Because your loop doesnt yeild inside it?

Comment: Agree with BugFinder,
your " while (true)" keep looping infinitely without no way to escape...
which of course make your Unity not responding